# "out of scope" error when iterating an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, class-cluster

Why am I getting an "out of scope" error whenever I try to access the "url" variable in this loop?

```
for(NSString *url in self.winnerImageURLs) {
        [mediaItemString appendFormat:@"{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"%@\",\"href\":\"%@\"},", url, url];
    }
```

The class of very item in the "self.winnerImageURLs" NSMutableArray comes back as NSCFString so I'm not sure what the dealio is here.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong???

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a debugger quirk. Have you tried using NSLog to determine whether the string you're building appears to be correct?

Comment: Yup.  Did NSLog when I added the NSString into the mutable array .. and in debugger ensured that there is a single element in the array of type NSCFString.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you're concerned about the type itself, NSCFString is the underlying runtime type of instances of NSString and CFString to support bridging between Cocoa frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about accessing the url variable in the debugger, it happens quite a lot.  It's not a problem in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Short anwer is that it is supposed to be like that. A longer answer is that `NSString` is a class cluster.

**Class cluster**

> A class cluster is an architecture
>   that groups a number of private,
>   concrete subclasses under a public,
>   abstract superclass. The grouping of
>   classes in this way provides a
>   simplified interface to the user, who
>   sees only the publicly visible
>   architecture. Behind the scenes,
>   though, the abstract class is calling
>   up the private subclass most suited
>   for performing a particular task.

Many common `Cocoa` classes are implemented as class clusters, including `NSArray`, `NSString`, and `NSDictionary`.

You create and interact with instances of the cluster just as you would any other class. Behind the scenes, though, when you create an instance of the public class, the class returns an object of the appropriate subclass based on the creation method that you invoke. (You don’t, and can’t, choose the actual class of the instance.)

**NSString example**

```
NSString *a = @"UTF32.txt";

NSString *b = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:a];

NSTextStorage *storage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:b];

NSString *c = [storage string];
```

Each of a,b and c may be (and in 10.5 is) an instance of a different private subclass (and in fact, on Mac OS X v10.5, each is). Although each of the objects is of a private subclass of `NSString`, it’s convenient to consider each of the objects to be instances of the `NSString`  class.

About **Class Clusters** in Apple Developer site: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34